# iPhone IMAP GMail push

Tags: gmail, imap, ios, apns

Seeing as [Yahoo (japan) got imap push to iOS devices working today](http://help.yahoo.co.jp/help/jp/mail/mobile/mobile-20.html#1) (it's working on my phone now), is there a way to set it up with a GMail account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gmail doesn't offer IMAP push for iOS (IMAP idle isn't supported by iOS Mail), but [Google Sync](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=138740) (which actually uses MS exchange mobile protocol) which doesn't only push your mails but also syncs your contacts and calendars (if you wish to).

---

*As of Janury 30, 2013, [Google terminated Active Sync support for free users](http://googleblog.blogspot.ca/2012/12/winter-cleaning.html).*

Comment: Ok well I'm using that for the Calendar, but as far as I remember when trying the mail it didn't give a push notification alert (You got mail! thing) when new mail arrived.

Comment: Watch out to use Google Sync, not iCal, and also make sure you didn't configure IMAP for mail and Google Sync only for calendar (and maybe contacts). I'm quite sure Google Sync pushed Mail to my iPhone - used it for quite some time.

Comment: Posted followup question here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86985/